# Plotting ellipsoid with coordinate axis

Tags: plotting, visualization, parametric-functions

I would like to visualize the difference in coordinate shift for the ellipsoid using Mathematica. [image: different parametrisations]

The above is a screenshot from wikipedia. What I need is to visualise the difference between measuring from a pole and measuring from the centre.

Also do anybody know the coordinates of (theta, phi) of the pole and the equator? I am little bit confuse about these things. A help in visualisation is really appreciated.

Comment: In spherical coordinates $\theta$ is called the [colatitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colatitude).

Comment: Just check the document of `ParametricPlot3D` and `Manipulate`.